# what is the difference between strcspn() and strpbrk()?

Tags: c++, c, string, function

```
char * strpbrk (char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Returns a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of any of the characters that are part of str2, or a null pointer if there are no matches.

```
int  strcspn( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

The length of the initial part of str1 not containing any of the characters that are part of str2.

seems both work same , is there any major differences?

Comment: One returns an index, the other a pointer. Other than that, they're basically identical.

Answer (score 5):

These functions are hardly having any application in C++ programming. Well I think so. But still if you want to know about it here is the answer,

In your question `strcspn` returns a character position **whereas** `strpbrk` returns a pointer.

Also by chance if no character is found, `strpbrk` returns **a null pointer**; IIRC, under the same circumstances `strcspn` returns the **index of the NUL** at the end of the string.

Also I had got a descent explanation about [strcspn()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) and [strpbrk()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strpbrk/). Check the link.